# 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am getting this error when I call my method dismissView. Here is the method stub:

```
-(IBAction)dismissView
{
    RootViewController *rootController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:rootController animated:YES];
}
```

That should work, and I've checked, rootController is initialized and allocated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had this problem recently and solved with something like this...

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Comment: swift 3 implementation `let _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController((self.navigationController?.viewControllers[1]) as! HomeViewController, animated: true)`

Answer (score 13):

The `-popToViewController` is used to pop view controllers OFF the stack, down to one that already exists. Your `UINavigationController` has a stack of ViewControllers (stored in the `viewControllers` property), when you `popToViewController`, you're going to want to pass one of the elements in that array as the first argument.

What you most likely want to do in this case is use `-popViewControllerAnimated:`, which will remove the top `ViewController` from the stack

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4**

For anyone still looking for a better solution that doesn't involve the *UINavigationController* stack indexes, which is getting more problematic with bigger navigation stack - here's the easiest way to solve this:

```
if let destinationViewController = navigationController?.viewControllers
                                                        .filter(
                                      {$0 is DestinationViewController})
                                                        .first {
    navigationController?.popToViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Why not do `$0 is DestinationViewController` instead `$0.classForCoder == DestinationViewController.self` ?

Answer (score 6):

You're allocating the RootViewController right there. It does not exist in the navigation controller's stack, so no matter how far you pop, you won't reach it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Storyboads, use this segue:

```
#import "PopToControllerSegue.h"

@implementation PopToControllerSegue

- (void) perform
{
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;

    for (UIViewController* controller in sourceViewController.navigationController.viewControllers) {
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:destinationViewController.class]) {
            [sourceViewController.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
            return;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"PopToControllerSegue has failed!");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Push Segues you can easily go back to the root using this method:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

When using Modal Segues (because of the word **dismiss** in the question and as a general reference) you can `dismiss` the view controller using this method:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

The `UINavigationController` has a stack of `ViewControllers` which is stored in the viewControllers(NSArray) property. Enumerate to the required `ViewController` and pop to that `ViewController`.

Following code should solve the problem.

```
-(IBAction)dismissView
{
    NSArray *array = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    for (id controller in array) {
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[RootViewController class]]) {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one line solution.

**Swift 4+:**

```
self.navigationController?.popToViewController ((self.navigationController?.viewControllers[1]) as! Your_ViewController, animated: true)
```

**Objective-C:**

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I was in the root ViewController and this works only for VCs that are stacked over it.
To pop to the RootViewController use

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before popToViewController, check that NavigationController contains your ViewController:

```
if navigationController.viewControllers.contains(entryViewController) {
    navigationController.popToViewController(entryViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
self.navigationController?.present(viewControllers, animated: true, completion: nil)
```